# Office 365 Developer tenant: automatic renewal

Tags: office-365, administration, office-365-developer, subscriptions

**Quote from [Office 365 Developer Program FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/office-365-developer-program-faq)**

> In April 2019, we transitioned to a new model where your subscription
>   can be renewed perpetually every 90 days if you're actively using it
>   for development. We believe that this model ensures that developers
>   who are actively developing solutions have a subscription for as long
>   as they need one. If you're developing frequently, your subscription
>   never expires; it is automatically extended.

**Renewal procedure**

> Your subscription is good for 90 days and can be renewed for another
>   90 days for as long as you're using it for development activity.

**Question**

What exactly do we have to do to renew the dev subscription? What are the minimum dev-related activites that will auto-renew our subscriptions?

Comment: they're probably using the same metric they used to calculate sandbox points. :)

Comment: or maybe resource quota? Since sandbox is dead anyway.